# The Purple Periodic Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, chemistry

Below is a periodic table that's hiding a secret word.

Can you find out what's strange about this purple periodic table and find the answer.

[image: Puzzle]

Text-only version:

```
H                                                                   He
Li  Be                                          B   C   N   O   F   Jo
Na  Mg                                          Al  Si  P   S   Cl  Ar
K   Ca  Sc  Dc  V   Cr  Mn  Fe  Co  Ni  Cu  Zn  Ga  Gn  As  Se  Br  Kr
Rb  Sr  Y   Zr  Nb  Mo  Tc  Ru  Rh  Pd  Ag  Cd  In  Sn  Sb  Te  G   Xe
Cs  Ba  La  Hf  Ta  W   Re  Os  Fe  Pt  Au  Hg  Tl  Pb  Bi  Po  At  Rn
Fr  Ra  Ac  Rf  Db  Sg  Bh  Hs  Mt  Ds  Rg  Cn  Nh  Fl  Mc  Mp  Ts  Og

        Ce  Pr  Nd  Pm  Sh  Eu  Gd  Tb  Ky  Ho  Lr  Tm  Yb  Lu
        Th  Pa  U   Np  Pu  Am  Cm  Bk  Cf  Is  Fm  Ba  No  Lr
```

*Note: The color purple is not relevant to solving the puzzle; it just worked well for the name :)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The elements in this table that are wrong are:

> [image]

With this mistakes, we can see that

> each letter from A to P appears exactly once as a wrong letter. Taking the letters that *should* be there, in A-P order, gives **DMITRII MENDELEEV**, the inventor of the periodic table.

Comment: Also worth noting that rot13(Gur svefg gjb yrggref va gur frdhrapr ner ercynpvat Zraqryrivhz, gur ryrzrag anzrq nsgre uvz.)