# The Green Periodic Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, chemistry

<sup>This puzzle follows from the [Purple Periodic Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107514/the-purple-periodic-puzzle) (these puzzles are solved individually).</sup>

Another strange periodic table has appeared and it's hiding a secret word.

Can you find out what's strange about this green periodic table and find the answer?

[image]

Text-only version:

````
H                                                                   He  
V   O                                           I   C   N   Be  F   Ne  
Na  La                                          Al  Ho  P   S   Cl  Ar  
K   Ca  Sc  Ti  Li  Cr  Mn  Fe  Co  Ni  Cu  Zn  Ga  Ge  As  Se  Br  Kr  
Rb  Sr  Y   Zr  Nb  Mo  Tc  Ru  Rh  Pd  Ag  Cd  In  Sn  Sb  Te  B   Xe  
Cs  Ba  Mg  Hf  Ta  W   Re  Os  Ir  Pt  Au  Hg  Tl  Pb  Bi  Po  At  Rn  
Fr  Ra  Er  Rf  Db  Sg  Bh  Hs  Mt  Ds  Rg  Cn  Nh  Fl  Mc  Lv  Ts  Og   
 
        Ce  Pr  Nd  Pm  Sm  Eu  Gd  Tb  Dy  Si  Ac  Tm  Yb  Lu          
        Th  Pa  U   Np  Pu  Am  Cm  Bk  Cf  Es  Fm  Md  No  Lr          
```
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wrong elements

> seem to be switched in pairs:
>
>  [image]

So what do we do with this?

> The atomic numbers here don't have any zeroes, and there's a fairly even distribution of digits - all of the nonzero digits appear at least once.
>
>  We can choose one of the elements from each pair, along with its new atomic number, to get all the digits from 1-9 once:
>
>  3=V / 4=O / 67=Si / 12=La / 89=Er / 5=I
>
>  Sorting these new letters from 1-9, we get **LAVOISIER**, an early chemist who was one of the first to attempt to list the chemical elements.

Comment: Darn it! I was just writing an answer. *grumbles*

Comment: Great job! Of course this is the right answer, but I noticed there seems to be a small error in the image. Er should go to Ac and Ho to Si.